# VBA WinHTTP to download file from password proteced https website - saved file corrupted

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, https, download

I have searched for a solution to this issue having first researched via Mr Excel and also elsewhere on this site (specifically question 22051960 which appears to be closed to new users like me).
The site I am attempting to download from is :
https://downloads.theice.com/
and it appears that the main site is an html page requesting authorisation credentials.

I have tried the code the above referenced thread which appears to successfully open the main site, authenticate and save the file; however, when I navigate to the file it is not the file on the site but is instead only 1kb and not in excel format. Here is the code from that thread:

```
Sub SaveFileFromURL()

Dim FileNum As Long
Dim FileData() As Byte
Dim WHTTP As Object

mainUrl = "https://downloads.theice.com/"
fileUrl = "https://downloads.theice.com/Settlement_Reports/Oil/icecleared_oil_2017_01_24.xlsx"
filePath = "C:\mydownloads\myfile2.xls"

myuser = "username"
mypass = "password"

'@David Zemens, I got this by examining webpage code using Chrome, thanks!
strAuthenticate = "start-url=%2F&user=" & myuser & "&password=" & mypass & "&switch=Log+In"

Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")

'I figured out that you have to POST authentication string to the main website address not to the direct file address
WHTTP.Open "POST", mainUrl, False 'WHTTP.Open "POST", fileUrl, False
WHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WHTTP.Send strAuthenticate

'Then you have to GET direct file url
WHTTP.Open "GET", fileUrl, False
WHTTP.Send

FileData = WHTTP.ResponseBody
Set WHTTP = Nothing

'Save the file
FileNum = FreeFile
Open filePath For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
    Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
Close #FileNum

MsgBox "File has been saved!", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

I have reasonable vba skills within excel but have no experience of html or web-page functionality and so am lost as to how to resolve this issue.
My ultimate aim is to utilise the authentication code within a routine I have written which automatically saves files from a list of URL's in an excel spreadsheet which already works for non-protected url's.

I hope this is an acceptable question for this forum
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should set the credentials (`SetCredentials` method) before sending your request on your `WinHttpRequest` instance.

Something like this

```
WHTTP.SetCredentials(myuser , mypass , HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER);
```

Could you also have a look on below links?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384058(VS.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383144(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384076(v=vs.85).aspx

I hope this will help you